# Is there any way to show tooltip by default (without hover pie chart) on chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have implemented the chartjs. And used piechart. Currently tooltip shows on hover. Is there any way to show the tooltip by default?

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand, you want to always show a tooltip for a given data segment

You can use following code snippet:

```
var pieChart = $("#chartContainer").dxPieChart({
    dataSource: data,
    series: {}
}).dxPieChart("instance");

pieChart.getSeries().getPointByArg("Second").showTooltip();
```

See [working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaatula/M6gxY/1/)

And [demo here](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartsadvancedfeaturesdoughnuttooltip)

Comment: what's dxPieChart? The OP posted a question for chartjs.

Comment: @hitautodestruct I'm not aware about any library with name "chartjs". I know Chart.js project, charting library based on cavas, and I know ChartJS project, currently part of DevExtreme product.